# How to get form element value when triggered using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've worked with JQuery to get data from a specific form element when triggered

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#select-box-name').change(function(){
        $('#div-result').load('run-a-routine.asp?value=' + $('#select-box-name').val());
    });
});
</script>


<form id="my-form">
    <select id="select-box-name">
        <option value="1">Fred Bloggs</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is there a way of setting the **.change** trigger to the form

```
$('#my-form').change
```

and using javascript to detect which form element was selected/changed and get its value

Comment: $('#div-result').load('run-a-routine.asp?value=' + $(this).val());

Comment: There isn't any such kind of trigger for `form` but yea definitely you can check whether form has been changed or not before doing any operation!

Comment: Yes, there is way. But what do you mean by _which form element_. Do you have multiple elements in the form? If yes, why are they not in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `form`'s [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, which will be trigger when any input in the `form` changed its value, as `input` will bubble up, you can catch it at the form, and use `e.target` to find out the source. And do anything with that source.

```js
$('#test').on('input', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var id = $target.attr('id');
  var val =$target.val();
  console.log(id + "'s value change to :" + val );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" id="t1"/>
  <input type="text" id="t2"/>
  <select id="s1">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="a">b</option>
    <option value="a">c</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id='ta1'></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank's fuyushimoya. This code slipped past me. Perfect. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is , 
1.check each element change and set a param to true , if change happen in the form

```
$("form :input").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').data('changed', true);
});

$("form :select").change(function() {
 $(this).closest('form').data('changed', true);
});
```

then check if some changes happen in following way

```
 if($(this).closest('form').data('changed')) {
  //do something
 }
```

May be it will be helpfull to you

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** while there is no `change` event, there is `input`. Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31450581/601224) from [fuyushimoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737627/fuyushimoya)

---

There is no `change` handler on the `<form>` element, but you can easily select all the form elements that can change like this:

```js
$("#my-form").find("input, textarea, select").on("change", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id") + " changed to: " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
    <input id="input_1" type="text" /><br />
    <textarea id="textarea_1"></textarea><br />
    <select id="select_1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select_2">
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks aorcsik, that's 99% there. If I had 3 <select> elements in the form, is there no way of determining the "id" of the <select> element that triggered the event. By reading the other posts, I'm assuming not.

Comment: You can determine which element changed, `this` in the callback refers to the object which changed. See my edited snippet.